# D3.js x value scaling problem from Array of objects

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Editing my question from earlier!

I did look into this post:
*[D3: ordinal scale not working with array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28819363/d3-ordinal-scale-not-working-with-array-of-objects)* However I still have problems despite adjusting my code.

**My Question**

I am trying to display my Array of objects on a chart:

```
const sbjList = [ {'name':'French', 'number':30},
              {'name':'English', 'number':20},
              {'name':'Maths', 'number':26},
              {'name':'Geography', 'number':38},
              {'name':'Science', 'number':34} ];
```

with categorical variables on x-axis (names) and numerical values on the y-axis;
and I have this code:

```
//scaling y values
const yScale12 = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(sbjList, (d, i) => +d['number'])])
  .range([0, height2]);

//scaling x values
const xScale12 = d3.scaleBand()
  .domain(sbjList.map( (d, i) => d[i]['name']))
  .rangeRound([margin.top, margin.top + sbjList.length * height2 ]) 
  .padding(0.5)
```

I get this error message on the console:
`Unexpected value NaN parsing y attribute.`

Rest of the code tries to display the above logic on chart:

```
//select the container
d3.select("#a2")
  .append('svg')
    .attr('width', width2 + margin2.left + margin2.right)
    .attr('height', height2 + margin2.top + margin2.bottom)
    .append('g')
      .attr('transform',`translate(${margin2.left}, ${margin2.top})`)
      .selectAll('rect')
        .data(sbjList)
        .enter().append('rect')
          .style('fill', 'steelblue')
          .attr('width', xScale12.bandwidth() )
          .attr('height', d => yScale12(d) ) //???????????
          .attr('x', (d, i) => xScale12(i) )
          .attr('y', d => height2 - yScale12(d) )
```

Looks like the problem is happening in the line marked by `//???????????`.

Where is this problem coming from? All items going on y-axis are numeric. How can I change my code so my chart shows up on browser?

Comment: You're passing the whole object to the scale. It should be `yScale12(d.number)` instead.

Comment: Thanks. That took care of the error!

Answer (score 0):

you should use

```
domain([0, d3.max(sbjList, (d, i) => +d['number'])])
```

not

```
domain([0, d3.max(sbjList, (d, i) => +d[i]['number'])])
```

because `i` is the index of the current array element being iterated through.

and `d` is the element of the array itself.

so `d[i]` will be the element with index `i` within **`d` element** which you don't have.

Comment: Thanks! I tried that before as well, but there is another error which I saw earlier before this problem: Unexpected value NaN parsing y attribute. I thought d [ i ] would drill into my array but it did not! Using [0,38] also causes this error, so I think I need to figure out this error now!